# How do I specify where to save files that result from running the unix split command?

Tags: unix, split

Is there a way to tell the split command to save the resultant files in a particular location?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

How about:

```
$ split -b 10 input.txt xxx/split-file
```

or

```
$ split -b 10 input.txt /tmp/split-file
```

Just include the output directory in the prefix specification. Keep in mind that the directory must be created beforehand.

Comment: ahh!  The answer being that in the unix man page for split when it says "prefix" it means the file name prefix __AND__ the path...

Answer (score 1):

This is the MacOS X (BSD) version of split, and includes some features of `csplit`:

> split [-a suffix_length] [-b byte_count[k|m]] [-l line_count] [-p pattern] [file [name]]

The `name` specifies the prefix to the file name - the default is `x`, effectively `./x`.

So, you do:

```
 split bigfile /lots/of/little/files/here
```

#### POSIX

The POSIX definition of [`split`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/split.html) gives the synopses:

> ```
> split [-l line_count] [-a suffix_length] [file [name]]
>
> split -b n[k|m] [-a suffix_length] [file [name]]
> ```

(The web site has a repeated typo - no space between `file` and `[name]`.)